# ls $FOLDER_PATH with space in $FOLDER_PATH: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to get the filename in a folder with only one file in it.

FYI: The `$FOLDER_TMP` contains a space in it, that is why I use `printf`

```
function nameofkeyfile(){
    FOLDER_TMP="${PWD%/*/*}/folder/"
    FOLDER=$(printf %q "${FOLDER_TMP}")
    FILENAME=ls "$FOLDER" # Error: No such file or directory
    # or this: FILENAME=$(ls "$FOLDER") # Error: No such file or directory
    FNAME=`basename $FILENAME`
}
```

The problem is the line:
FILENAME=ls "$FOLDER" # Error: No such file or directory

Do you know why - and yes the folder is there?
And if I echo the `$FOLDER` it gives me the right folder.

Comment: If your version of `find` supports `-printf`, I'd suggest using `find "$FOLDER_TMP" -type f -printf %f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to get the filename in a folder with only one file in it.

You definitely have the wrong approach.

Instead, consider using globbing like so:

The assignment

```
fname=( "${PWD%/*/*}"/folder/* )
```

will populate the *array* `fname` will the expansion of the given glob: that is, all files in the directory `"${PWD%/*/*}"/folder/`, if any. If there are no files at all, your array will contain the glob, verbatim.

Hence, a more robust approach is the following:

```
nameofkeyfile() {
    fname=( "${PWD%/*/*}"/folder/* )
    # Now check that there's at most one element in the array
    if (( ${#fname[@]} > 1 )); then
        echo "Oh no, there are too many files in your folder"
        return 1
    fi
    # Now check that there is a file
    if [[ ! -f ${fname[0]} ]]; then
        echo "Oh no, there are no files in your folder"
        return 1
    fi
    # Here, all is good!
    echo "Your file is: $fname"
}
```

This uses Bash (named) arrays. If you want the function to be POSIX-compliant, it's rather straightforward since POSIX shells have an unnamed array (the positional parameters):

```
# POSIX-compliant version
nameofkeyfile() {
    set -- "${PWD%/*/*}"/folder/*
    # Now check that there's at most one element in the array
    if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
        echo "Oh no, there are too many files in your folder"
        return 1
    fi
    # Now check that there is a file
    if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
        echo "Oh no, there are no files in your folder"
        return 1
    fi
    # Here, all is good!
    echo "Your file is: $1, I'll store it in variable fname for you"
    fname=$1
}
```

I didn't strip the full path from the filename, but that's really easy (don't use `basename` for that!):<sup>1</sup>

```
fname=${fname##*/}
```

More precisely: in the Bash version, you'd use:

```
fname=${fname[0]##*/}
```

and in the POSIX version you'd use:

```
fname=${1##*/}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>there's a catch when using parameter expansions to get the basename, it's the case of `/`. But it seems you won't be in this case, so it's all safe!

Answer (score 2):

To store the output `ls "$FOLDER"` in a variable, put it in a sub-shell:

```
FILENAME=$(ls "$FOLDER")
```

Another problem is the `printf`.
It adds escaping backslashes in the string,
and when you try to list the directory in the next step,
those backslashes are used literally by the shell.
So drop the `printf`:

```
function nameofkeyfile() {
    FOLDER="${PWD%/*/*}/folder/"
    FILENAME=$(ls "$FOLDER")
    FNAME=$(basename $FILENAME)
}
```

Lastly, it's better to use `$(...)` than `` `...` ``: